# Index BTree Storage

Tags: mongodb

How is a collection B-Tree Index saved?

Is it like each index bucket saved within the data portion of a record?

Does this mean that for every collection within a database, there are a dedicated number of extents that cover an specific index for an specific collection of an specific database?

Comment: What difference would it make to your life and profession if that was (a) true and (b) false?

Answer (score 0):

Every b-tree bucket is allocated as needed and thus has it's own location within the data file. They are not specifically stored near the data it's referring to (nor is there any reason to).

Answer (score 0):

B-tree is basically an concept or a set of algorithms, not a complete file storage specification. Everything you ask about is up to the implementor.